# String does not get saved in DB varchar column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I've got this code inserting a row in my table:

```
$activation_code = str_random(60);
$user = User::create([
    'email'           => $input['email'],
    'password'        => Hash::make($input['password']),
    'name'            => $input['name'],
    'surname'         => $input['surname'],
    'bio'             => $input['bio'],
    'birthdate'       => $input['birthdate'],
    'gender'          => $input['gender'],
    'smoker'          => (int)$input['smoker'],
    'activation_code' => $activation_code
]);
```

This is from the model class:

```
protected $hidden = [
    'id',
    'password',
    'password_temp',
    'active',
    'activation_code'
];

protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'password',
    'name',
    'surname',
    'bio',
    'birthdate',
    'gender',
    'driving_style',
    'smoker',
    'university'
];
```

All the other fields are being inserted correctly apart from `activation_code`.

I checked like thousand times the `activation_code` column in the DB and the name, type, size are correct, etc. I tried inserting just a dummy string like `ifohsdfiuhsfhdsiofdhs` and it still does not insert it. I dumped the randomly generated string and it is a `string(60)`, so it's not empty.

I tried inserting that string manually in the DB and it worked fine.

I get no errors whatsoever... I am simply clueless as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fillable` array needs to contain `activation_code`. `hidden` and `fillable` attributes do not share a relationship. Your `activation_code` data does not get added to the model because it is not on the 'whitelist' (`fillable`).

`hidden` is used to hide sensitive data which you are correctly using in the scenario.

Your `fillable` array should look like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'password',
    'name',
    'surname',
    'bio',
    'birthdate',
    'gender',
    'driving_style',
    'smoker',
    'university',
    'activation_code'
];
```

Comment: Now it works! 
But that's weird... I tried stating the `activation_code` in the `fillable` array before and it didn't work.

Comment: @Milkncookiez, from the code you provided that is the issue that stands out, other than that I am not sure.